# ¿por qué me sale class TypeError?

Tags: python, revisión-de-código

es que esta función se trata de ingresar un diccionario de diccionarios que contiene un nombre como llave y un diccionario con el nombre de los trabajos entregados por los estudiantes como llave y la nota como valor en cada una de ellas.
La función me sirve cuando solo ingresa un diccionario con un solo estudiante (un diccionario dentro de otro diccionario), pero cuando ingresan 5 o más sale  *class 'TypeError'* (5 diccionarios dentro de un diccionario que los contiene a todos).

```
def calcular_estadisticas_completas(estudiantes_tareas: dict)->dict:
tareas_datos_max={}
for est in estudiantes_tareas:
    estudiante=est
    tareas=estudiantes_tareas[est]
    for tarea in tareas:
        nota=int(tareas[tarea])
        tarea_datos={}
        if tarea in tareas_datos_max:
            tarea_dat=tareas_datos_max[tarea]
            if nota>tarea_dat.get("mayor"):
                tarea_dat["mayor"]=nota
                tarea_dat["menor"]=estudiante
            if nota<tarea_dat.get("menor"):
                  tarea_dat["menor"]=nota
                  tarea_dat["peor"]=estudiante
            tarea_dat["total"]=(tarea_datos.get("total"))+nota
            tarea_dat["cantidad"]=(tarea_datos.get("cantidad"))+1
            promedio=(tarea_datos.get("total"))/(tarea_datos.get("cantidad"))
            tarea_dat["promedio"]=promedio
            tareas_datos_max[tarea]=tarea_dat
        if tarea not in tareas_datos_max:
            tarea_datos={"mayor":0,"mejor":None, "menor":100, "peor":None, "promedio":0, "cantidad":1, "total":nota}
            if nota>int(tarea_datos.get("mayor")):
                tarea_datos["mayor"]=nota
                tarea_datos["mejor"]=estudiante
            if nota<int(tarea_datos.get("menor")):
                tarea_datos["menor"]=nota
                tarea_datos["peor"]=estudiante
            tarea_datos["promedio"]=(tarea_datos.get("total"))/(tarea_datos.get("cantidad"))
            tareas_datos_max[tarea]=tarea_datos

return tareas_datos_max
```

Comment: Hola Angela, coloca siempre la **traza completa del error** y no solo el tipo, hay muchas causas para un TypeError y además faltan datos para poder reproducir tu código, la traza contiene información muy relevante como la linea que causa la excepción además de mensajes propios de cada una aclarando su causa.

Comment: _(El programa terminó su ejecución antes de tiempo: revise su envío para descubrir qué pudo haber pasado. Detalles del error inesperado: <class 'TypeError'>)_ 
Es que el envío de es por una página que prueba los códigos automáticamente y no me dice más que eso de arriba. 
Un ejemplo del diccionario que ingresa es el siguiente:
{"Sofia": {"Tarea 4": 50, "Tarea 2" : 90},"Alejandra": {"Tarea 1": 80, "Tarea 4" : 60}, "Luis": {"Tarea 2": 40, "Tarea 3" : 93}}  Las claves son los nombres y las llaves serían el diccionario con sus notas y la tarea correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

El TypeError significa que se intentó realizar alguna operación con parámetros que no son del tipo esperado. Por ejemplo `10 / 'str'` generaría *TypeError: unsoported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'*

Ejecuté tu código en el IDLE de python 3.6 que tengo en mi compu y la línea que dice `if nota<tarea_dat.get("menor"):` genera el error *TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'*

Al analizar el porqué se produce, noté que en la línea anterior asignas `tarea_dat["menor"]=estudiante` con lo cuál se asigna un str a tarea_dat['menor'] lo cual es erróneo y que es probable que sea un error de tipeo. En lugar de menor debiera ser mejor.

Al corregir esta línea, se generan otros errores similares. Ejemplo, en la línea que acumular el total `tarea_dat["total"] = (tarea_datos.get("total")) + nota` si es la primera vez que se agregó esa tarea tiene asignado `None` generando un nuevo TypeError. Esto puede solucionar utilizando el segundo parámetro `tarea_datos['total'] = tarea_datos.get('total', 0) + nota`

Pienso que lo que está dificultándote el razonamiento es como hacer para agregar una tarea la primera vez al resultado. Existe un "patrón" de como acumular/agrupar valores en un diccionario que podría aplicarse para resolver el ejercicio:

```
datos = {'uno': 1, 'dos': 3, 'uno': 5}
resultado = {}

for k in datos:
    if k not in resultado: # agrega clave faltante
        resultado[k] = 0
    resultado[k] += datos[k] #Acumula el valor
```

Además también se puede tomar ventaja de las propiedades de los dict y del for de python. 
Te dejo una versión simplificada de tu función con algunas anotaciones para que puedas estudiarlas:

```
def calcular_estadisticas_completas(estudiantes_tareas: dict) -> dict:
    resultado = {}
    #for k, v in dict.items() te permite iterar el diccionario 
    #poniendo la clave in k y el valor en v
    for estudiante, tareas in estudiantes_tareas.items(): 
        #hacemos lo mismo con las tareas
        for tarea, nota in tareas:
            #si la tarea aún no está en el resultado, 
            #la agregamos con los valors predeterminados
            if tarea not in resultado: #se podria haber utilizado resultado.setdefault
                resultado[tarea] = {
                    'mayor': -1, #MinValue: presupongo que no se puede sacar menos que 0
                    'mejor': None,
                    'menor': 101, #HighValue: presupongo que nadie puede sacar más de 100
                    'peor': None,
                    'cantidad': 0,
                    'total': 0,
                    'promedio': 0,}

            #A partir de acá, si o sí tendré la tarea en resultado 
            #con lo cual puedo realizar los cálculos
            tarea_actual = resultado[tarea] #Tomo una referencia a la tarea actual 
                                            #que está en resultado. Los cambios cambios a 
                                            #tarea_actual se realizan sobre
                                            #resultado[tarea]. Es para no sea
                                            #tan largo no más.

            if nota > tarea_actual['mayor']:
                tarea_actual['mayor'] = nota
                tarea_actual['mejor'] = estudiante

            if nota < tarea_actual['menor']:
                tarea_actual['menor'] = nota
                tarea_actual['peor'] = estudiante

             tarea_actual['cantidad'] += 1
             tarea_actual['total'] += nota
             tarea_actual['promedio'] = tarea_actual['cantidad'] / tarea_actual['total']

    return resultado
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Me gustó realmente analizar este problema y me ayudó a aprender más sobre Python. Saludos.